# Creating <td> elements with customer behavior on the fly in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just getting started with jQuery, and I've had some success so far. I've created a handler that updates a <table> every time a user makes a selection from a dropdown. It looks mostly like this:

```
function loadAttributes() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ws/itemSearch/getAttributesForItemType",
    contentType: 'application/xml',
    data: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.itemsearch.foo.com/">'
          + '<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ser:getAttributesForItemType>'
          + '<arg0>' + this.value + '</arg0>'
          + '</ser:getAttributesForItemType></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>',
    processData: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        var attributes = '<table summary="Attribute Section"><tr class="underline">';

        var attCount = 0;

        $(data).find("return").each(
            function() {
                if (++attCount % 4 == 0) {
                    attributes += '</tr><tr class="underline">';
                }

                // TODO PMA click handler to the new <td> element
                attributes += '<td>' + this.textContent + '</td>';
            }
        );

        attributes += '</tr></table>';

        $("div[id=attributes]").html(attributes);
    }
});
}
```

As you can see my next step is to not just add literal <td> elements to the row containing the attributes, but to add a click handler to them. This click handler would append the contents of the <td> to a text box; something like:

```
tdItem.click(function() {
    $("input[name=search]").append(tdItem.textContent);
}
```

To do that, I'd prefer to create each td item as a separate Element and build up the table in an object-oriented manner using <tr> elements rather than pasting together a literal string which is what I'm doing now. Most of the examples on the jQuery site have to do with adding listeners to existing elements and not to building up a new section of the document like this on the fly every time. At the very least, can someone point me to a good tutorial on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. You should be able to hook up the event handlers once the TR/TDs have been added to the DOM.

Comment: Well, this works to add the click listener:

$("td[id=attr]").click(function() {
    $("input[name=search]").append(this.textContent);
   });

(I changed the code so that it adds the "attr" id to each of the <td>s I create). But append() isn't the right way to add text to the <input> - I'll look into how to do that correctly.

Comment: Assuming you want to append the td text to the existing value of the input, you could try:

var input = $("input[name=search]");
input.val(input.val() + this.text());

Comment: @patmortech yep that's it - discovered that on my own after a bit of poking around.

Comment: See my answer for a different approach to your handlers, even though this does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple to achieve and I would recommend taking advantage of some jQuery functions when writing your html building.

First `$("<tr></tr")` will create a tr element stored in a jQuery object as if you had just selected it.  If you are building html as above I would recommend changing to something like this in your success function.

```
    var attributes = $('<table summary="Attribute Section"></table>');

    var attCount = 0;
    var attributeRow = $('<tr class="underline"></tr>');

    $(data).find("return").each(
        function() {
            if (++attCount % 4 == 0 && attCount != 0) {
                attributes.append(attributeRow.clone());
                attributeRow = $('<tr class="underline"></tr>');
            }

            // TODO PMA click handler to the new <td> element
            var attribute =  $('<td>' + this.textContent + '</td>'); 
            attribute.click(function(){//click function});              
            attributeRow.append(attribute );

        }
    );
    //add the last attribute row
    attributes.append(attributeRow);
    $("div[id=attributes]").append(attributes);
```

Above you will notice that You now have the attribute td generated as a jQuery object that you can apply click functions to.

Comment: Fancy! This is much cooler than what I was doing. Thanks for helping me learn "best practices".

Comment: I find that this route gives me the most opportunity to split things out for later use.  I have also found that knowing how to build a jquery plugin has given me a much better idea of how best to use jquery functions.  There are lots of good how to's out there but I recommend starting at the source http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

Comment: Does this code actually work? Shouldn't you be appending the attribute (td) to the attributeRow, and not to the attributes variable?

Comment: Damn good point @patamortech!  Edited.  I also noticed I forgot to add the last attribute row.

Comment: @patmortech, you're right - that line should be "attributeRow.append(attribute)" just tested it. Otherwise works great!

Comment: @jonathan-park, saw your last-second edits there too - everything is working swimmingly. Now I just need to figure out how to code my actual click handler correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that with string literals is to add an `onclick` attribute to your `td` elements like

```
 attributes += '<td onclick="somefunction();">' + this.textContent + '</td>';
```

that would work, but I would not recommend that. To stay unobtrusive, use jQuery objects for table creation. For instance

```
  success: function(data) {  
    var $table = $('<table summary="Attribute Section"></table>');

    $table.append($('<tr class="underline"></tr>'));

    var attCount = 0;  

    $(data).find("return").each(  
        function() {  
            if (++attCount % 4 == 0) {  
                $table.append($('<tr class="underline"></tr>').append($('<td/>', {
                    click:   function(e){
                         alert($(this).text());
                    }
                }))); 
            }  
        }  
    );  

    $("div[id=attributes]").empty().append($table);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, a more elegant approach to your click handling for the td's is to put one click handler on the table itself, and let it catch the click events that bubble up from the td's. That way you don't need to worry about adding handlers to each td in the table. It's also better for performance, though in this situation, I doubt it matters much in that regard.

Here's what you would do (you could add this right after you declare the $table variable):

```
$table.click(function(e) {
   var target = $(e.target);

   if (target.is('td')) {

      var input = $('input[name=search]');
      input.val( input.val() + target.text() );

      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```